# Error when passing a 'system::string' to a function

Tags: c++, string, c++-cli

I have the following function, which will hopefully tell me whether or not a folder exists, but when I call it, I get this error -

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'std::string'

The function -

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>

bool directory_exists(std::string path){

    struct stat fileinfo;

    return !stat(path.c_str(), &fileinfo);

}
```

The call (from the form.h file that holds the form where the user selects the folder) -

```
private:
    System::Void radioListFiles_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        if(directory_exists(txtActionFolder->Text)){                
            this->btnFinish->Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Is anyone able to tell me how to filx this? Thanks.

Comment: I never expected to see anyone using C++/CLI, STL *and* POSIX functions all in the same call...

Comment: @Matteo : Yes, it's quite an abomination...

Comment: It's almost like I'm not very expirenced with C++, hence the need to ask for help! I apprciate that you probably had a chuckle, but have some pity for me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert from a managed, C++/CLI string (`System::String^`) into a `std::string`.  There is no implicit conversion provided for this.

In order for this to work, you'll have to handle the [string conversion yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).

This will likely look something like:

```
std::string path = context->marshal_as<std::string>(txtActionFolder->Text));
if(directory_exists(path)) {  
     this->btnFinish->Enabled = true;
}
```

That being said, in this case, it might be easier to stick to managed APIs entirely:

```
if(System::IO::Directory::Exists(txtActionFolder->Text)) {  
     this->btnFinish->Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the second example works perfectaly. As you probably guessed, I'm not that expierenced with C++ (examples coming from the internet!), so that's why things are a bit mixed up.

Comment: @DavidGard Realize that there's really two "languages" in play here - C++, and C++/CLI, which is the .NET C++ "language binding".  If you're using C++/CLI, I tend to try to stick to as much .NET options as possible...

Comment: +1 for being the first to mention `System::IO::Directory::Exists`.

Comment: I'm slowly realising that this is the case, but I expect I'll have several more questions yet!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert a CLR string to a STL string to convert it to a C-string to use it with a POSIX-emulation function. Why such a complication? Since you are using C++/CLI anyway, just use [`System::IO::Directory::Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to convert from the managed type `System::String` to the native type `std::string`.  This involves a bit of marshaling and will result in 2 separate string instances.  MSDN has a handy table for all of the different types of marshaling for strings

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

In this particular case you can do the following

```
std::string nativeStr = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managedStr);
```